# How to set relation between Product Sales and Product Costs Tables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

probably basic question but I need help how to set up relations between my models.

1. I have the first model SalesData, where I import from csv sales data of products for particular periods - so this table can contain a product multiple times with different dates, quantities and sales:

```
class SalesData(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField("Date", null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.CharField("Product", max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    sales = models.DecimalField("Sales", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity", null=True, blank=True)
```

2. I have the second model ProductCosts, where I have the product and its production costs. And one product can have only one specific production costs.

```
class ProductCosts(models.Model):

    product = models.CharField("Product", max_length=150)
    costs = models.DecimalField("Costs", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

And I need help with:

1. how to connect these two tables to be able to get production costs for particular product to each row in SalesData table, so I will be able to calculate profit, margin etc. for particular rows?
2. what to do, to be able to create form, where I can fill production costs for rows, where are these costs missing for new sales data inputed to table? And if it is possible to have the form as a table with products with missing costs in the first column and in the second column to have blank fields for missing production costs and to be able to fill and save all missing costs to ProductCosts table, if is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create a separate model for product and have foreign key relationship from sales data, and production costs to this model. Like so

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SalesData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Date", null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales = models.DecimalField("Sales", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Quantity", null=True, blank=True)


class ProductCosts(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    costs = models.DecimalField("Costs", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Now your two tables are linked through Product table.

To calculate the profit on each row you can use annotate. Ypu can change the formula according to your needs.

```
from django.db.models import F
SalesData.objects.annotate(profit=(F('sales')-F('product__productcosts__costs')))
```

For creating a form you can register your models with the [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) and to edit them there. There is also the option have it editable in [list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for help. I applied suggested solution and I assume now, that I have to in following order 1. fill product name, 2. fill costs and then 3. I can upload sales data. I cannot upload sales data for missing products and production costs. Is there some way to go backwards and 1. fill sales data and after that 2. create form where I can fill missing product name and costs - and this form will be presented as table. Or at least to have form with product name and missing costs - also as table - in first column to have product name and in the second to have blank fields for costs?

Comment: You can allow foreign key in SalesData model to be null so that you can add sales data without creating a product. But then you will run into problems when you have to create product and then link it to the sales data. I would suggest that when you create product data when you are creating sales data if the product doesn't exists. You can add production costs later.

Comment: Thanks for answer and is there some way how to create product where Sales data entered. As I have function to populate data from csv to SalesData model and currently I am using following code which for missing product from Product model will fill "xxx" text - but if there is way how to push product name from sales data to product model, it would be great.  
`try:
    sd.product = Product.objects.get(name=str(line["Items"]))
except:
    print(str(line["Items"]))
    sd.product = "xxx" `

Comment: you can try using get_or_create so if the product with a name doesn't exists it will create it.

Comment: thanks a lot, updated my code with get_or_create and it creates new product when not in database, so it works: 

 try:
            sd.product = Product.objects.get(name=str(line["Items"]))
        except:
            print(str(line["Items"]))
            sd.product, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name=str(line["Items"]))